# python gspread import csv to specific work sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

Is there a straight forward way to import data from a CSV file to a **specific** 
**work** **sheet** using gspread?
The default is always sheet1, as mentioned in the documentations.

If there is none, what would be the most economical approach regarding "google API Write Requests"?

Comment: A real .csv file just have one "sheet", if not, you must have an file with a modified extension (like a .xlsx).

Comment: I meant a specific google worksheet. Is it not clear from the question? Should I edit it?

Comment: I guess not, was my bad

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- You want to put the CSV data from a file to the specific sheet in a Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using gspread.
- You have already been able to put and get values for Spreadsheet using gspread.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? In this sample script, I used `values_update()`. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script:

```
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheetId = '###'  # Please set spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = 'Sheet2'  # Please set sheet name you want to put the CSV data.
csvFile = 'sample.csv'  # Please set the filename and path of csv file.

sh = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sh.values_update(
    sheetName,
    params={'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'},
    body={'values': list(csv.reader(open(csvFile)))}
)
```

#### Note:

- Please import `csv` like `import csv`.
- This sample script supposes that the shee of "Sheet2" is existing in the Spreadsheet.
- In this sample script, the CSV data is put from the cell "A1" of "Sheet2" in the Spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [values_update()](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_update)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks! that seems to work. Does this call (import the data from the csv file with "value_update") will be considered as one write requests in the google sheet API? I am trying to save "Quota" to stay within the 100 seconds limit.

Comment: @Iddos Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Yes. When I saw the script of gspread for `values_update()`, it uses [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update). In this case, when `values_update()` is run, one quota of Sheets API is used.