# How to upload to sheet 2 using gspread

Tags: python, gspread

```py
import gspread
sh = gc.open("Nameofsheet")
content = open("file.csv", "r").read().encode("utf8")
gc.import_csv(sh.id, content)
```

This code to upload csv to google spreadsheets in first sheet.

```py
worksheet = sh.worksheet("Sheet2")
```

But how I can to upload CSV to second sheets?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python gspread import csv to specific work sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264871/python-gspread-import-csv-to-specific-work-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Hi using the method `import_csv()` you cannot do that. As mentioned in the documentation, it erases the content of the spreadsheet and create a single sheet with the content of the CSV file.

> Imports data into the first page of the spreadsheet.

https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.4.0/api/client.html?highlight=import#gspread.Client.import_csv

If you wish to fill up the second sheet with the content of the CSV, you can:

1. Open the CSV
2. Read a line
3. Put this line in the spreadsheet
4. Repeat to step 2.